# How can i display message like 'disk does not exist' if disk sdb is not present on server

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

How can i display message like 'disk does not exist' if disk sdb is not present on server.

i tried below things but it did not work.

```
  - debug:
     msg: "disk does not exist"
    when: ansible_devices != "sdb"

  - debug:
     msg: "disk does not exist"
    when: item.key != "sdb"
    with_dict: "{{ ansible_devices }}"

  - debug:
     msg: "disk does not exist"
    when: ansible_devices.sdb == "false"
```

Thanks,

Comment: For the record. This question is not [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It's `a specific programming problem`.

Answer (score 1):

`ansible_devices` is a dictionary of the devices. There are more options how to find out whether a device exists or not.

1) Let's create a list of the devices and **search the list of the devices**. For example

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Disk nvme0n1 exists.
      when: "'nvme0n1' in ansible_devices.keys()|list"
    - debug:
        msg: Disk sdb does not exist.
      when: "'sdb' not in ansible_devices.keys()|list"
```

gives

```
"msg": "Disk nvme0n1 exists."
"msg": "Disk sdb does not exist."
```

---

2) It's also possible to **test if the variable is *defined* or not**. For example, this play gives the same result

```
    - debug:
        msg: Disk nvme0n1 exists.
      when: ansible_devices.nvme0n1 is defined
    - debug:
        msg: Disk sdb does not exist.
      when: ansible_devices.sdb is undefined
```

---

3) It's also possible to use the fact that **an empty variable evaluates to False**. For example, this play gives the same result

```
    - debug:
        msg: Disk nvme0n1 exists.
      when: ansible_devices.nvme0n1|default('')
    - debug:
        msg: Disk sdb does not exist.
      when: not ansible_devices.sdb|default('')
```

Comment: Thank you Vladimir.. tried second option and worked

Comment: just wondering how to see what return value variable gives back ?
like in above case we can check 1) 'ansible_devices.sdb' whether defined or undefined 2) for ansible_os_family == 'Debian' . here we are checking with ==
but from where one can see whether need to use defined or undefined or == or with something else ?